# Mixed up 32Bit and 64bit shared object / libraries

Tags: linux, 64-bit, shared-libraries

Accidentally I mixed up between 32Bit and 64Bit library files on my x86 embedded Linux system. I'm now trying to find out which .so-File could be the wrong one.

Do you know any tool to analyze .so files?

In my strace logs I found calls to fstat64(). Which .so-file contains the fstat() routine?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`file(1)` can quickly tell you whether a shared object is 32-bit of 64-bit. Try:

```
file /lib/*.so*
```

Answer (score 1):

readelf -h /path/to/yourelf